# How to trigger Accordion on clicking of a Button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, hide, accordion

I want to trigger accordion when I click minimize button or to be more specific, when we click the minimize button the dialog’s content part gets hidden.

Html Code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Title">
<div>
<p>Some Content</p>
</div>
</div>
<button>Minimize</button>
```

Script Code:

```
$(function (){
$("#dialog").dialog();
$("button").button({icons:{primary: "ui-icon-minus"},text: false}).insertBefore('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(){ 
$("#dialog").accordion({collapsible: true});
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger the accordion on the dialog widget instead of the original `<div>` element. You also need to explicitly specify the title bar as the accordion header:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("widget").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    header: "> .ui-dialog-titlebar"
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9mDW/).

**EDIT:** An accordion might not be the best choice to collapse a dialog to its title, especially if you only want the button to trigger the effect. Maybe you can just use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead:

```
$("#dialog").slideToggle("fast");
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n9mDW/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want only content to be collapsed and title should remain as it is when I click the button.

Comment: @Piyush, the title did remain before I applied styles, but you're right, clearly the accordion is messing something up :) I got it to work by specifying the header selector, see my updated answer.

Comment: édéric Thanks a ton, that's indeed a great solution, I've been trying to do this but not able to achieve the result. Now, only thing left is that whole title bar is acting as a header (click anywhere in the bar), but I want only minimize button to do the thing.

Comment: @Piyush, in that case, maybe you don't need an accordion. Answer updated accordingly :)

Comment: édéric Awesome, that's exactly what I want to do :))